# Using Google Cloud Storage with Google Data Prep

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I am using Google Cloud Storage to store CSV files. These CSV files get updated daily with new data in them. I'm hoping to use Google Data Prep to automate the process of cleaning these files and then combining them. Before I start to build this process, I am curious if this is a good way to use this platform. The CSV files will be in the same format each time. Are there any cause for concern if the files get updated on a daily basis? Or possible errors that could arise that I don't know about?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for Google Cloud Dataprep.  You can parameterize your inputs.  See https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Parameterization_118228665 and https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628